# react d3 tree library svg styles are not seeing on the tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, d3.js, d3tree

I have an svg design like this:

[true svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTITa.png)

when I put this svg into the Tree component with renderCustomNodeElement prop, svg changes like this:

[broken svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbvr9.png)

Does anyone know why is this happening?

You can see the full code from here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/rd3t-v2-custom-svg-tag-forked-dp4bbt?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When viewing your code in the inspector, you can see the following class is added to your elements:

```
.rd3t-node {
    cursor: pointer;
    fill: #777;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 2;
}
```

Those stroke attributes are what's causing it. I cannot immediately tell what's causing it, but it seems to be a class added by the react-d3-tree library.

I added the following to your styles.css, which fixed it.

```
svg .rd3t-node {
    stroke-width: 0px;
}
```

Note that if you add anything that has a stroke to your svg, this might also mess with the stroke. It would be better to check the `react d3 tree` documentation to see if you can override it in a better way.

Comment: You are a hero! Very appreciate.